# showing the function is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(E, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f: E \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function.

Suppose that $(E, \mathcal{A}, \mu)=(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure. Show that the function $F$ defined by
$$
F(x):= \begin{cases}\int_{[0, x]} f \mathrm{~d} \lambda & \text { if } x \geq 0, \\ -\int_{[x, 0]} f \mathrm{~d} \lambda & \text { if } x<0,\end{cases}
$$
is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.
Can someone give me idea on how I can approach, thank you.

Comment: What do you know about  $f$?

Comment: is $f$ just any Lebesgue integrable function?

Comment: You cannot omit such basic information in the question. Hint for solution: Any continuous function with finite limits at $\pm \infty$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: I am very sorry. I will add the missed portion in question.